# Node version conflict | two different versions installed

Tags: node.js, homebrew

This is a very odd issue, but it looks like I have two different versions of Node installed.  I didn't think that this was possible.

Does anyone have advice on how to fix this or an explanation of what's going on?

```
$ node -v
v4.5.0
$ brew upgrade node
Error: node 7.5.0 already installed
```

Comment: I guess `node` is referring to the one first accessible by the system, and the one brew uses is the one located in the path where brew installs its packages.

Comment: Ok does that mean there's an issue here or I'm fine as is?

Comment: Please refer to top answer for this: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/171530/how-do-i-downgrade-node-or-install-a-specific-previous-version-using-homebrew

Comment: Try running the `which node` command to see what the node command is linking to. If I remember correctly Homebrew requires that you add a link to your .bashrc file to use the Homebrew-installed version of Node.

Comment: You can also use `brew info node` if I'm correct and you'll also see the install path

Comment: @JoshuaKleveter this is the path I get after running that command: /usr/local/bin/node

Comment: I'm just conscious I have two different versions and would have peace of mind if I removed one?

Comment: Depends. If you remove the default node install other things might not work.

Comment: @Filth Okay. 1st: no need to worry about the dual version install. The CLI is still linked to the apple-installed version of Node, and you don't want to remove that. 2nd: When you run `brew install node` there is a completion output that is printed near the end of the install process. It should show what you need to add to your .bashrc file to get the Homebrew version of Node linked to the CLI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a more detailed overview of what I addressed in the comments:

## What's Going On?

Your CLI's `node` command is still linked to the version of Node that is installed by Apple. You *do* have two versions of Node installed, but that's not an issue, as this is expected when installing Node with Homebrew.

## How to Fix

I did a bit more research, and in your case you just need to run `brew info node` and look in the 'caveats' section of the output. It should have a string that needs to be added to your .bashrc file so your CLI will link the `node` command to the Homebrew-installed version rather than the version that Apple provides.  In this case, though, I always preferred to use [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) (also available through Homebrew) to manage my Node versions. It made it much easier to handle upgrades, etc.  Either way works, though.